# Logging tools for ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, logging

I am looking for a logging service that can logg things, example  if a AD user change a value on a entity object by  changing the value inside the DDL and then submits the form in the view it should get logged somewhere.

like:

> "Robert Johnson changed value on column_Race to "cat" on this
>   column_name."

Any kind of tips is appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [built-in tracing capabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx) of the .NET framework. Another possibility is to use a third party logging framework such as [log4net](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/) which is a commonly used logging framework for .NET.

Comment: Whats your opinions regarding this? http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=logging-block

Comment: It's heavy artillery. It's good but the question is whether you need all those features or a simple trace could do the job. It will depend on your application complexity and specific requirements. I would probably try to see if the basic things work before getting into the Microsoft Enterprise Blocks.